# TortoiseSVN + Assembla hangs on update/commit

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, assembla

I am experiencing a kind of strange problems with TortoiseSVN and an Assembla repository. Sometimes, when I try to update or commit the UI opens but nothing happens. It occurs more and more often.

I got this situation with TotoiseSVN 1.8 and 1.9. TortoiseSVN DebugString show that it hangs on call SVN::GetRepositoryRootAndUUID(line 2052)

Debug traces got with DebugView:

- 00000001  0.00000000  [8156] #5 Thread:10040 done (32017624 µs)
- 00000002  0.00013048  [8156] #6 Thread:10040 SVN::GetRepositoryRootAndUUID(line 2052) svn_client_get_repos_root Path=https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/[REPO]
- 00000003  0.00102066  [8156] #6 Thread:10040 done (923 µs)
- 00000004  0.03112921  [8156] #7 Thread:10040 SVN::Update(line 405) svn_client_update4
- 00000005  0.03131152  [8156] #7 Thread:10040 done (129 µs)
- 00000006  8.15056133  [12804] #1 Thread:11204 SVNReadProperties::Refresh(line 132) svn_client_proplist4 Path=C:/SandBoxes/[trunk]
- 00000007  8.15182590  [12804] #1 Thread:11204 done (1312 µs)
- 00000008  8.19760704  [12804] #2 Thread:13328 SVNStatus::GetStatus(line 244) svn_client_status5 Path=C:/SandBoxes/[trunk]
- 00000009  8.19952869  [12804] #2 Thread:13328 done (1948 µs)
- 00000010  8.19955921  [12804] #3 Thread:13328 SVN::GetWCRootFromPath(line 1944) svn_client_get_wc_root Path=C:/SandBoxes/[trunk]
- 00000011  8.20054817  [12804] #3 Thread:13328 done (975 µs)
- 00000012  8.20071888  [12804] #4 Thread:13328 SVN::GetHEADRevision(line 2093) svn_client_url_from_path2 Path=C:/SandBoxes/[trunk]
- 00000013  8.20092201  [12804] #4 Thread:13328 done (210 µs)
- 00000014  8.20126534  [12804] #5 Thread:13328 SVN::GetRepositoryRootAndUUID(line 2052) svn_client_get_repos_root Path=https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/[REPO]

> I changed my repo name and URL by [trunk] and [REPO] in logs.

Did someone know how to fix this or a workaround?